# SQL Query to represent employee check-in and check-out - Working Hours in a day and nights

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have table record as

```
id              | int
badge_id        | varchar
status          | enum('check_in','check_out')
timestamp       | datetime
```

Database has data as

```
id  badge_id         status          Timestamp

1   EMP0001         check_in        2021-11-22 08:00:00
2   EMP0002         check_in        2021-11-22 08:00:50
3   EMP0001         check_out       2021-11-22 13:00:00
4   EMP0002         check_out       2021-11-22 13:01:00
5   EMP0001         check_in        2021-11-22 13:31:00
6   EMP0002         check_in        2021-11-22 13:33:50
7   EMP0001         check_out       2021-11-22 18:03:00
8   EMP0002         check_out       2021-11-22 18:04:00
9   EMP0003         check_in        2021-11-22 17:00:00
10  EMP0004         check_in        2021-11-22 19:00:50
11  EMP0003         check_out       2021-11-22 21:30:00
12  EMP0004         check_out       2021-11-23 00:22:00
13  EMP0003         check_in        2021-11-22 22:01:00
14  EMP0004         check_in        2021-11-23 00:55:50
15  EMP0003         check_out       2021-11-23 03:30:00
16  EMP0004         check_out       2021-11-23 05:38:00
```

Day shift and Night Shift (finishing next day)

I am trying to get hours worked by each of them works well for day shift but now able to do the same for night shift. Any suggestions?

Code to fetch:

```
SELECT
    id,
    MIN(timestamp) AS check_in_at,
    MAX(timestamp) AS check_out_at,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp))/60 AS total_time
FROM cte where timestamp BETWEEN '2021-12-27' AND '2021-12-30'
GROUP BY
    badge_id,date(timestamp)
ORDER BY
    badge_id,timestamp;
```

Expected result:

```
badge_id    Check_in_at     Check_out_at        Total_time

EMP0001     2021-11-22 08:00:00 2021-11-22 18:03:00 7.9500
EMP0002     2021-11-22 08:00:50 2021-11-22 18:04:00 7.9833
EMP0003     2021-11-22 17:00:00 2021-11-23 03:30:00 10.3000
EMP0004     2021-11-22 19:00:00 2021-11-23 05:38:00 10.3800
```

Can someone suggest me the query?

Comment: Can you please identify which version of MySQL you use. In version 8.0 of MySQL `window functions` were added to the product which may be useful here.

Comment: yes correct, i am using mysql 8.0

Comment: Please do inform us of the version in your next question - it helps get your answer faster. I have simplified my answer below but it does not use window functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot exactly match your expected output because I don't understand how (for example) `2021-11-22 08:00:00 2021-11-22 18:03:00` is just 7.95 hours when it is 10.05 hours by my calculation. Also, there is a check_in/out done during the day so there are 2 possible calculations, one that excludes the break and another that ignores the break.

Note I have opted to use `correlated subqueries` in the first cte to align the earliest check in with latest chack out over a 1 day interval which enables the final result to allow for shifts that span midnight. Also note that the where clause to limit the date range of data should be present in this first cte.

```
with cte as (
    select distinct
          t.badge_id
        , (select min(s.timestamp) 
           from mytable s
           where t.badge_id = s.badge_id and t.timestamp > date_sub(s.timestamp,interval 1 day)
          ) check_in_at
        , (select max(s.timestamp) 
           from mytable s
           where t.badge_id = s.badge_id and t.timestamp < date_add(s.timestamp,interval 1 day)
          ) check_out_at
    from mytable t
    /* where t.timestamp >= '2021-12-27' and t.timestamp < '2022-01-01' */
    )
select
      badge_id
    , check_in_at
    , check_out_at
    , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, check_in_at, check_out_at)/60 AS total_time
from cte
order by
      badge_id
    , check_in_at
```

The result (from the sample data) is:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| badge_id |     check_in_at     |    check_out_at     | total_time |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| EMP0001  | 2021-11-22 08:00:00 | 2021-11-22 18:03:00 |    10.0500 |
| EMP0002  | 2021-11-22 08:00:50 | 2021-11-22 18:04:00 |    10.0500 |
| EMP0003  | 2021-11-22 17:00:00 | 2021-11-23 03:30:00 |    10.5000 |
| EMP0004  | 2021-11-22 19:00:50 | 2021-11-23 05:38:00 |    10.6167 |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bcc8a20047bf603bdf55abd299841678)*

Previous query as requested (produces different result):

```
with cte1 as (
    select
          t.id
        , t.badge_id
        , t.timestamp as check_in_at
        , (select o.timestamp from mytable as o
           where t.status = 'check_in' and o.status = 'check_out'
           and o.badge_id = t.badge_id
           and o.timestamp > t.timestamp
           order by timestamp
           limit 1)
          as check_out_at
    from mytable t
    /* where timestamp BETWEEN '2021-12-27' AND '2021-12-30' */
    )
, cte as (
    select
        *
        , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, check_in_at, check_out_at)/60 AS total_time
    from cte1
    where check_out_at is not null
    )
SELECT
  badge_id
, date(check_in_at) AS date_check_in
, MIN(check_in_at) AS check_in_at
, MAX(check_out_at) AS check_out_at
, SUM(total_time) as total_time_with_break
, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(check_in_at), MAX(check_out_at))/60 AS total_time_no_break
FROM cte 
GROUP BY
    badge_id, date(check_in_at)
ORDER BY
    badge_id, date(check_in_at)
```

Comment: Previous one was working.. this doesn't seems working... doesn't work if you have lots of data on that tables.... i need data on daily basis however this codes shows entire in one entry.

Comment: Sorry is it possible to provide previous Query..? @Paul

Comment: It is always possible to display the revisions(edits) of an answer by clicking on the link, at the centre, just below the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70573520/revisions - but I have also added the previous query it for convenience.